# Protractor doesn't wait for redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I've got protractor's code written with Jasmine that is supposed to log in the user. Unfortunately there's a redirect going on after going to root url that takes quite some time (about 5 seconds) and I cannot make protractor wait for it. I've already tried `browser.wait`, I've tried using promises, I've tried with [this blogpost](http://docsplendid.com/archives/209), but nothing did it. It still doesn't wait. The login page is a page from Keycloak server, that's why I use `driver.findElement` instead of `element`. Here's my current code:

```
describe('my app', function() {
  it('login', function() {
    var driver = browser.driver;
    browser.get('/');
    console.log('get');
    driver.findElement(by.id('username')).isPresent().then(function() {
      console.log('waited');
      driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys("test");
      driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("test");
      driver.findElement(by.id('kc-login')).click();
      driver.findElement(by.css('.page-header')).isPresent().then(function() {
        console.log('ok');
        expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("/test");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Do you know what can I do to make it work? I've started protractor project with this seed: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *turn the synchronization off*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

describe('my app', function() {

  beforeEach(function () {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      browser.get('/');
  });

  it('login', function() {
    var username = element(by.id('username'));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(username), 10000);

    username.sendKeys("test");
    element(by.id('password')).sendKeys("test");
    element(by.id('kc-login')).click();

    var header = element(by.css('.page-header'));

    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(header), 10000).then(function () {
        console.log('logged in');
    });
  });
});
```

Note that I've also updated the test: switched back to `element` and `browser`, added `browser.wait()` with built-in *Expected Conditions*.

Comment: The above code didnt work for me. I get a wait timed out error